# Synchronizing access to FFI calls in Rust (via a global RWLock?)

Tags: multithreading, locking, rust, ffi

I'm trying to build a Rust wrapper for a C FFI library, but the underlying library has some functions which are not thread-safe. To access these functions, I need some kind of global lock which will protect the C library's state.

Is there any way to use a global `std::sync::RWLock` or similar mechanism to control access to the C library?

Various obvious solutions fail because Rust does not allow non-trivial global initializers:

```
error: function calls in constants are limited to struct and enum constructors [E0015]
example.rs:18 static global_state_lock: RWLock<()> = RWLock::new(());
```

Comment: I don't think that is possible without using unsafe code. You should pass the lock, it's `Sync+Send` so you won't have any problem.

Answer (score 6):

This problem can be solved using [`sync::mutex::StaticMutex`](http://doc.rust-lang.org/sync/mutex/struct.StaticMutex.html):

```
extern crate sync;
use sync::mutex::{StaticMutex, MUTEX_INIT};

static LIBRARY_LOCK: StaticMutex = MUTEX_INIT;

fn access_global_resource() {
    let _ = LIBRARY_LOCK.lock();
    unsafe { call_thread_unsafe_c_api(); }
}
```

Many thanks to arrrrrrr1 on #rust, who pointed me in the right direction.

Comment: This API seems to be in flux. For more information, see: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/19379

Comment: The API appears to be have been deprecated in favor of the `lazy_static` crate. Any examples on how to do this with that?